# Rademacher average involving minima

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis

Let $B\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be the Euclidean $d$-dimensional unit ball.
It is well-known that for any $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in B$, we have the following upper bound on the Rademacher complexity
$$ R_n := \mathbb{E}\sup_{w\in B}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(w\cdot x_i)\le\sqrt n,
$$
where the expectation is over the Rademacher sequence $\sigma$, distributed uniformly in $\{-1,1\}^n$.
Suppose I am interested in the following quantity:
$$ R_{n,k}
:= \mathbb{E}
\sup_{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_k\in B}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i\min\{
w_1\cdot x_i,
w_2\cdot x_i,
\ldots,
w_k\cdot x_i\}
.
$$
I think I can show that $R_{n,k}=O(k\sqrt n)$, but I'm wondering if a better dependence on $k$ is possible. Logarithmic would be very nice, if true!

Comment: Logarithmic is surely out of question. You cannot do better than $\sqrt{kn}$. Let me know if $\sqrt k$ instead of $k$ makes any difference for you.

Comment: Hi @fedja! I can get $\sqrt{kn}$ but with extra log factors -- can you get a bound that's strictly $O(\sqrt{kn})$?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I certainly can try when I have free time and am not too tired. It is a funny problem. Just confirm that you still do care about it (otherwise I'll think of something else) :-)

Comment: I do care :) my solution with the log factors is pretty elementary, and I'd love to see how to shave them off...

Comment: Your "min" should be a "max", yes?

Comment: @usul it doesn't matter, by symmetry

Comment: @fedja it looks like the log(k) factor can't be removed: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07924

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a writeup of the $O(\sqrt{k\log k})$ bound:
[https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/rademacher-max-hyperplane.pdf](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Ekaryeh/rademacher-max-hyperplane.pdf)

Update: 23-Jul-2018: Assuming the claims here are correct, the $\log k$ factor cannot be removed
https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07924

Update: 17-Sep-2018: The previous calculation at the link had a mistake, giving the wrong dependence on $n$. After fixing it (see link above), we get a bound of
$$
O\left(\sqrt{\frac{k\log k\cdot(\log n)^3}{n}}\right).
$$

Update: 19-Dec-2021: The claim in my original writeup is correct (up to constants), but the proof is not! Here is (hopefully) a correct proof:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04763
(see Thm. 3 for the claim and the Discussion section for a careful explanation of previous mistaken attempts).